# С# Unity не могу разобраться со скоростью перемещения камеры

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-android, unity3d-editor

В проекте используется основная камера с режимом orthographic и поворотом на 45 и 30 градусов по X и Y. Каким образом можно изменить код, чтобы камера перемещалась с одной скоростью вверх/вниз и влево/вправо? В текущем варианте из-за изменения только двух координат не могу получить одинаковую скорость (камера перемещается вверх и вниз очень медленно). Координата Y же не изменяется т.к. это высота и из-за неё не получается правильно ограничить камеру.

```
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        isDragged = true;
        touchStart = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
    }
    else if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
    {
        isDragged = false;
    }
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0) && isDragged == true)
    {
        Vector3 direction = touchStart - Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        direction.y = 0;

        Vector3 newPosition = Camera.main.transform.position + direction;
        newPosition.x = Mathf.Clamp(newPosition.x, -45, 45);
        newPosition.z = Mathf.Clamp(newPosition.z, -45, 45);

        Camera.main.transform.position = newPosition;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему добавлением к X и Z координате Y:

```
        direction.x += direction.y;
        direction.z += direction.y;
        direction.y = 0;
```